# WebDriver JavascriptExecutor Not Working

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm trying to fill out text boxes on a web page with JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver. A coworker [this](https://github.com/dsheiko/autofill) github repository online for filling in the text boxes to speed things up.

When I run the program it will throw an error at `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("(function( window ) { 'use strict';"`, and then it moves through each text box, but it does not add the text to the box. My coworker and I looked at it for quite a while yesterday, compared our code, and were unable to figure out what is wrong. Here is my code and the errors that it produces.

Any help is appreciated.

**Java Code**

```
InputStream inputStream = ClientInformationComponent.class.getResourceAsStream("AutoFillClientInsuredComponent.js");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

try 
{
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (ClientDAO client : clients)
{
    String script = writer.toString();

    try
    {
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) 
        {
            //ERROR IS THROWN HERE webdriver.components.ClientInformationComponent.fill(ClientInformationComponent.java:128)
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("(function( window ) { 'use strict';"    
                    + "var lastName = '" + client.getLastName() + "';"
                    + "var firstName = '" + client.getFirstName() + "';"
                    + "var middleName = '" + client.getMiddleName() + "';"
                    + "var suffix = '" + client.getSuffix() + "';"
                    + "var streetAddress = '" + client.getMemberAddress() + "';"
                    + "var city = '" + client.getMemberCity() + "';"
                    + "var zipCode = '" + client.getMemberZipCode() + "';"                          + "var birthDate = '" + client.getDateOfBirth() + "';"
                    + "var homePhoneNumber = '" + client.getHomePhone() + "';"
                    + script);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**JavaScript File**

```
var document = window.document,
  fieldValueMap = {
        "LastName"              : lastName,
        "FirstName"             : firstName,
        "MiddleName"            : middleName,
        "Suffix"                : suffix,
        "MemberAddress"         : streetAddress,
        "MemberCity"            : city,
        "MemberZipCode"         : zipCode,
        "MemberZipCodeSuffix"   : memberZipCodeSuffix,
        "DateOfBirth"           : birthDate,
        "HomePhone"             : homePhoneNumber

  };

Object.keys( fieldValueMap ).forEach(function( name ){

    var input = document.querySelector( "form input[name='" + name + "']" )
                    || document.querySelector( "form select[name='" + name + "']" )
        || document.querySelector( "form textarea[name='" + name + "']" );

    input && input.type !== "hidden" && ( input.value = fieldValueMap[ name ] );
});

})( window );
```

**Error Log**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The     server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23    20:02:37'
System info: host: 'COL-ISD-D56345', ip: '10.8.11.30', os.name: 'Windows 7',   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Session ID: 10b4929d-001c-412c-94bc-ce9d006b6dd0 
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true,   elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true,   ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer,   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept, version=9,   ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false,   initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:22000/, handlesAlerts=true,   ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0,   ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
Command duration or timeout: 356 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision:   '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'COL-ISD-D56444', ip: '10.8.12.163', os.name: 'Windows  7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true,  ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false,  ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=9, platform=WINDOWS,  nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0,  webdriver.remote.sessionid=863d35b9-ff0d-4b83-b4e0-983d9272353d,  ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet  explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:22000/, takesScreenshot=true,  javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,  enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,  unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
Session ID: 863d35b9-ff0d-4b83-b4e0-983d9272353d
```

Comment: What driver you are using? Running in local or in grid? Does the generated JS code pass the linting?

Comment: @Purus Selenium IEDriver 2.44.0 and it is running in grid. I execute the Java code on my local machine, and it then runs the script on a VM through grid. My local PC is the server and the VM is the client. I have not used any specific linting software but does not show any errors in Eclipse when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out what the issue is. We are using IE 9 and the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676914(v=vs.85).aspx) states that if the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag is not present, IE 9 will display the page in *Quriks Mode* also known as *Compatibility Mode* by default.

By adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag would make the page render for IE 9 and not use Quirks Mode. You may also have to include a `meta` tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">` The `meta` tag also allows you to emulate a specific version of IE if needed by doing `content="IE=EmulateIE#` or `content=IE#`

The issues we were running into was that the JavaScript methods we were using were not supported by older versions of IE. We went through and tried changing some methods to the older style, but we continually ran into more and more compatibility issues with methods that were not supported in the older IE versions.